# Using php to post user submitted info to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I cannot get my code to work. I'm new to php/mysql but I am certain I am doing most things right here. I'm not getting any errors. With the code posted below, if I put info into the feilds and click the button the screen appears to refresh but when I check the mysql database I created, that info is not there.  I know that my connection to the database is working because I have fake data already entered into the database and the webpage is pulling it over and displaying it just fine.

The db.php is a separate file that contains the formatted php code for connecting to the database (server, username, password), which I know works because that is how I pull the data into the webpage as well.  And if it is needed, my server is set up for php 4.0.10.7 and I can't change that unfortunately.

So, here is my code:

```
<div class="a" id="add_customer">
<form id="customerdata" name="customerdata">
<input type="text" align="center" id="name" name="NAME" placeholder="Customer Name">
<input type="text" align="center" id="address" name="ADDRESS" placeholder="Address">
<b>Paid?:</b>
<select id="PAID" name="PAID">
<option value="select">Make a Selection</option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<input type="text" align="center" id="comments" name="COMMENTS" placeholder="Comments">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add Customer">
</form>
</div>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
include('db.php');
$database="mysql_database";

$con = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);

$sql="INSERT INTO mysql_database (NAME, ADDRESS, PAID, COMMENTS)
VALUES
('$_POST[NAME]','$_POST[ADDRESS]','$_POST[PAID]','$_POST[COMMENTS]')";
$a=mysql_query($sql);

if (!$a)
{
die("Error addding record. " . mysql_error());
}
else
{
echo "1 record added";
}
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: it could be many things, what is your SQL error?

Comment: Just confirming in your code snippet, you've got your database name the same as your table name?

Comment: Is your column name really in upper case? Column names are case sensitive. As well as the passed-on values.

Comment: @BrendanScarvell actually, no. They are different. I edited that info out and apparently didn't put the correct info there. It should be mysql_table_name I suppose. But even with the correct info in the correct places it is still just refreshing my screen but no adding anything to the database.

Comment: attributes inside $_POST should be included with quotations.

Comment: @LoganWayne Yes, I did check the column names. I have done a lot of reading in the last 6 hours and found that pitfall early on.

Comment: @codeSun like this `'$_POST["NAME"]` ?

Comment: @Rage : I would suggest : `...VALUES
(' ".$_POST['NAME']." ',...` (Because you are already using both quotations in your query, so to avoid any conflict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="a" id="add_customer">
<form id="customerdata" name="customerdata" method="post">
<input type="text" align="center" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Customer Name">
<input type="text" align="center" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Address">
<b>Paid?:</b>
<select id="paid" name="paid">
<option value="select">Make a Selection</option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<input type="text" align="center" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comments">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add Customer">
</form>
</div>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
include('db.php');
$database="mysql_database";

$con = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address= $_POST['address'];
$paid= $_POST['paid'];
$comments= $_POST['comments'];
$sql="INSERT INTO mysql_database (NAME, ADDRESS, PAID, COMMENTS)
VALUES
('$name','$address','$paid','$comments')";
$a=mysql_query($sql);

if (!$a)
{
die("Error addding record. " . mysql_error());
}
else
{
echo "1 record added";
}
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: Everyone submitted awesome advice. I've got a lot more reading to do to fully learn it all.

Answer (score 1):

1. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).
2. Inputs are not sanitized or [escaped](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), therefore vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
3. You are referencing the POST variables incorrectly. In your code, you are literally inserting '$_POST[NAME]'.
4. What table are you inserting into? That should be after `INSERT INTO`.

You should set all of the sanitized POST inputs into separate variables, however, this is what your current code could look like:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);

$sql="INSERT INTO table_name (NAME, ADDRESS, PAID, COMMENTS)
VALUES
('".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['NAME'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['ADDRESS']."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['PAID']."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['COMMENTS']."')";
$a=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if ($a)
{
echo "1 record added";
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  include('db.php'); //include db first

  $con = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password); //connect to db

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $database="mysql_database"; //I think this will not work.
     $sql="INSERT INTO $database (NAME, ADDRESS, PAID, COMMENTS) VALUES ('$_POST[NAME]','$_POST[ADDRESS]','$_POST[PAID]','$_POST[COMMENTS]')";
//Try this
$sql = "INSERT INTO (your_db_name) (NAME, ADDRESS, PAID, COMMENTS) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['address']."','".$_POST['paid']."','".$_POST['comments']."')"; //I used concantenation here

     $a=mysql_query($sql);
   }

   if (!$a) {
     die("Error addding record. " . mysql_error());
   }else{
     echo "1 record added";
   }
   mysql_close($con);
?>
Try this piece of code.
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not include the database when establishing your connection. Do this:

```
$con = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
```

Then on your INSERT query, instead of database name, change it to your table name

```
INSERT INTO mysql_table_name...
```

And use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to prevent [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) before you bind values to your query.

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["NAME"]);
```

And take note that `mysql_*` API is already [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and you should be using [mysqli prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead.

You can try the code below if you want to move to prepared statement. No need to sanitize manually the values, prepared statement will do this for you.

```
<?php

  /* ESTABLISH YOUR CONNECTION */
  $con = new mysqli($server,$username,$password,$database);

  if($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO mysql_table_name (NAME, ADDRESS, PAID, COMMENTS) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")){ /* CHECK IF THE QUERY IS TRUE */
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$_POST["NAME"],$_POST["ADDRESS"],$_POST["PAID"],$_POST["COMMENTS"]); /* BIND THE PASSED ON VALUES TO YOUR QUERY */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
    $stmt->close();
  } /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do this changes**

1. MySQL [Insert](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) function

   ```
   INSERT INTO <tbale_name> ......
   ```
2. MySQL DB Select

   ```
   mysql_select_db('database_name')
   ```
3. Make sure **table name and Database name** is correct (`mysql_database`)
4. make sure `include('db.php');` contain  `$server`, `$username`, `$password` **variables defined**
5. Make sure **input field `name=""` are Capital Letters**(`name="NAME"` or `name="Name"`). Bcz You use define `$_POST[NAME]` as Capitalized.
6. Don't just use `$_POST[NAME]`, T**his will be cause to** [**SQL Injection**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Use `mysql_real_escape_string`

   ```
    $name =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
   ```
7. **Don't use `MySQL`**, Bcz [This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

**So Final Code will be**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        include 'db.php';

        $database="mysql_database";

        $con = mysql_connect('$server','$username','$password');
        mysql_select_db($database);

        $name =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $address =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
        $paid =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['paid']);
        $comments =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);


        $sql="INSERT INTO <table_name> (name, address, paid, comments) VALUES('$name','$address','$paid','$comments')";

        $a = mysql_query($sql);

        if (!$a)
        {
            die("Error addding record. " . mysql_error());
        }
        else
        {
            echo "1 record added";
        }

        mysql_close($con);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<form>` tag is missing the `method` attribute, which by default is set to GET. This way, you're checking by the `$_POST["submit"]` existence but it can't be, 'cause you should instead use $_GET.

Try to specify `method="POST"` in the first place.

That said, you should seriously follow all the good advices already given in this thread about the deprecated `mysql` PHP extension (i.e. use `mysqli` instead) and possible SQL injection attacks prevention, using prepared statements with `mysqli`.

Use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [this](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/php/article.php/3599166/Connecting-and-prepared-statements-with-the-mysqli-extension.htm) as entry points to `mysqli` prepared statements, and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265319/15908) as a brief discussion about why prepared statements are a SQL injection countermeasure.